# error: resource mipmap/ic_launcher (aka com.example.i_am_rich:mipmap/ic_launcher) not found. error: failed processing manifest

Tags: android, flutter, appicon

Changed application icon in flutter by replacing the *mipmap* files inside *android/app/src/* which caused the above error.

I simply replaced the files with the ones for my app icon. However, I did change the name of my application icon.

Answer (score 0):

The issue happened because I named the app icon something other than "ic_launcher.png".

As you can see in the image attached:

The android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"> and the mipmap file must have the same name. If you name the application icon something else, it must match in the android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher">.

Which is located in android/app/src/main/AndroidManifest.xml and in build/app/intermediates/packages_manifests/debug/AndroidManifest.xml

[Click to view screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/coO8q.png)

Hope this helps someone else trying to learn flutter as myself. Feel free to correct me in anything if I am wrong.